# Filtering words from an array using another array as conditions

Tags: javascript, arrays, methods, filter, cpu-word

So I searched a lot in StackOverflow and other websites but I couldn't find the exact answer to my question. I want to make a new array that is the result of filtering the words of the "storyWords" array based on the "overusedWords" array. Basically, I want the result of my existing code but in another way. I tried using loops but it didn't work. Thanks for any help you may provide!!

```
let story = 'Last weekend, I took literally the most beautiful bike ride of my life. The route is called "The 9W to Nyack" and it actually stretches all the way from Riverside Park in Manhattan to South Nyack, New Jersey. It\'s really an adventure from beginning to end! It is a 48 mile loop and it basically took me an entire day. I stopped at Riverbank State Park to take some extremely artsy photos. It was a short stop, though, because I had a really long way left to go. After a quick photo op at the very popular Little Red Lighthouse, I began my trek across the George Washington Bridge into New Jersey.  The GW is actually very long - 4,760 feet! I was already very tired by the time I got to the other side.  An hour later, I reached Greenbrook Nature Sanctuary, an extremely beautiful park along the coast of the Hudson.  Something that was very surprising to me was that near the end of the route you actually cross back into New York! At this point, you are very close to the end.';

let overusedWords = ['really', 'very', 'basically'];
let unnecessaryWords = ['extremely', 'literally', 'actually' ];
let storyWords = story.split(' ');

console.log(storyWords.join(' '));
console.log(storyWords.length);

//Starting here is where my problem lays
let betterWords = storyWords.filter(function (word) {
    if(word === 'really') {
        return 0;
    } else if(word === 'basically') {
        return 0;
    } else if(word ==='very') {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return word;
    }
});
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score -1):

```js
let story = 'Last weekend, I took literally the most beautiful bike ride of my life. The route is called "The 9W to Nyack" and it actually stretches all the way from Riverside Park in Manhattan to South Nyack, New Jersey. It\'s really an adventure from beginning to end! It is a 48 mile loop and it basically took me an entire day. I stopped at Riverbank State Park to take some extremely artsy photos. It was a short stop, though, because I had a really long way left to go. After a quick photo op at the very popular Little Red Lighthouse, I began my trek across the George Washington Bridge into New Jersey.  The GW is actually very long - 4,760 feet! I was already very tired by the time I got to the other side.  An hour later, I reached Greenbrook Nature Sanctuary, an extremely beautiful park along the coast of the Hudson.  Something that was very surprising to me was that near the end of the route you actually cross back into New York! At this point, you are very close to the end.';

let overusedWords = ['really', 'very', 'basically'];
let unnecessaryWords = ['extremely', 'literally', 'actually' ];
let storyWords = story.split(' ');

//Starting here is where my problem lays
let betterWords = story.split(' ')
  .filter(function (val) {
    // Help with this function => https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce
    return !unnecessaryWords.reduce(function(current, next) {
      return current || val.toLowerCase() === next.toLowerCase();
    }, false);
  });
  
console.log(betterWords);
console.log(betterWords.join(' '));
```